# Xtightvnc: Ubuntu gnome-session-fallback: Fonts problem

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, fonts, vnc, fontconfig

I'm running a tightvnc server on Ubuntu 11.04 with a Gnome fallback session. Things seem to work fine except that when I try launching an application that needs `xfonts-100dpi`. All application menus are shown as little boxes instead of characters. It's as if the fonts are missing. The strange thing is, `xfonts-100dpi` is already installed and the same application runs fine if I log in to the box directly. Can you please help?

My `~/.vnc/xstartup`

```
unset SESSION_MANAGER
/usr/bin/gnome-session-fallback
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add in /etc/X11/xorg.conf

```
Section "Files"
FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
EndSection
```

Solve you problem?

Comment: I have already tried messing with the font path in the VNC server configuration. As suggested elsewhere on the Internet, I ran `xset -q` when physically logged in. From the resulting output, I took the FontPath and configured the `vncserver` Perl script to set the same FontPath. The fonts you're referring to were part of what I added to the path. It didn't help.

Comment: For the record, I tried your suggestion as well and no joy...